# jinja2 split filter in ansible

Tags: docker, split, ansible, jinja2

I am passing docker image as an argument to ansible playbook.
In the playbook, I need to grab the registry, repository names and tag into separate variables.

I am trying to use split filter.

```
- set_fact:
    registry: "{{ source_image.split('/')[0] }}"
    repo_and_tag: "{{ source_image.split('/')[1] }}"

- set_fact:
    repo: "{{ repo_and_tag.split(':')[0] }}"
    tag: "{{ repo_and_tag.split(':')[1] }}"
```

Instead of using split filter multiple times, is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the lists first, e.g.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    registry: "{{ _array.0 }}"
    repo_and_tag: "{{ _array.1 }}"
  vars:
    _array: "{{ source_image.split('/') }}"

- set_fact:
    repo: "{{ _array.0 }}"
    tag: "{{ _array.1 }}"
  vars:
    _array: "{{ repo_and_tag.split(':') }}"
```